# get generated autoincremental ID from MySQL after insertion by jugglingdb?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, compoundjs

I'm using compound library for nodejs,

The primary key is **autoincremental**, after insertion in db thru a model object, the object has the id as NULL, but in the database has the correct number, how to get this number after calling "save()"?

```
    var user = new User();
    user.name = Math.random();
    user.save();
    console.warn(user);//the user.id is null, not the number in db
```

ps: is there also a way to use custom primary key names in the model instead of always id?

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather old post, but in the event you are still looking for an answer;

Instead of using the synchronous save method I would suggest using the asynchronous create method.

For example:

```
var user = new User();
user.name = Math.random()

User.create(user, function (err, newUser) {
    console.log(newUser)
});
```

The returned "newUser" object will contain the newly created id.